# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'

Tags: python, conda, pypdf, seek, langchain

`I'm working on a langchain pdf qna project. But I'm getting this error.

File "c:\users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
exec(code, module.**dict**)

File "D:\pdf-chat\app.py", line 30, in <module>
main()

File "D:\pdf-chat\app.py", line 26, in main
rawtxt=get_text(docs)

File "D:\pdf-chat\app.py", line 9, in get_text
pdf_reader=PdfReader(pdf)

File "c:\users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2_reader.py", line 319, in **init**
self.read(stream)

File "c:\users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2_reader.py", line 1414, in read
self._basic_validation(stream)

File "c:\users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2_reader.py", line 1453, in _basic_validation
stream.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)`
Anyone knows the reason for this.
I tried changing various version of the PyPDF2 and even PyPDF modules but nothing works. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please include the relevant sections of code, we can't help if we're only given a error/traceback

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Don't `.read()` your file object after opening the file, just pass it to `PdfReader` as is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.